# Avoid navbar-toggler to change color when selected

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am dealing with a Bootstrap4 page having nav-bar with a navbar-toggler. 
The default behavior is that it changes the border color when selected. I'd like to avoid it but I can't see how.

See this example https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-top/

Answer (score 0):

It is not the border-color being changed, it is the `outline`.

Just overwrite the default styling with:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    outline: none;
}
```